# Cathode Ray Tube

Tags: atoms

I am considering the cathode ray tube of the set up, when the cathode rays were discovered

Voltage = Very High
Gas = any
Atmospheric Pressure = We change

(In the following example i am just changing the atmospheric pressure everything else is kept same)

At 
1 atmospheric pressure (atm) -> Tube Does not glow
0.1 atm -> The whole tube lightens
0.01 atm -> The tube glows at the anode end (Glowing is shown as there is a detector coating of ZnS)

[Note: I don't have this set-up this is just taken by me from theory]

My Question: why when i am just reducing the atm from 1 to 0.01 first it is not glowing then it glows completely and after that it glow just at one end. Why so?

[I am asking this question here because on chemistry forum i was suggested by someone to post it here too as it was related to plasma and people over here could help me better. [Link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8632/cathode-ray-tube) to my question on chemistry forum]